# Where can I see the first name of opponents?

Tags: top-spin-3

In Top Spin 3 on the PS3, is there a sure way to see the first name of opponents in single player mode, instead of just the initial (Marina Juegaldo instead of M. Ruegaldo)?

It seems the Tournament Results screen gives the full name of the winner, but I'm hoping for a more controlled way of seeing anyone's full name.